# windows partition wiped out with debian install CD and LVM

Tags: linux, boot, windows-10, debian, lvm

Going by my prehistoric knowledge on how to set up a dual boot with Windows and Linux, I set out to install debian over my Windows 10 installation. My single hard disk was originally partitioned into an OEM partition, a couple of recovery partitions and a primary OS partition. For the debian install, I shrunk this primary partition and created a new one for debian.

After booting into the Debian installer, I got to the partitions sections where I thought I would be presented the option of selecting my newly created partition which I created by shrinking my original 1TB one.

However, the LVM option I chose landed up overwriting my boot record, erasing all my original partitions and leaving my computer in a non bootable state

I think all the data is still there. I aborted before LVM could do any more damage. My disk does not have a recognizable file system now.

The error I get is
"The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors". I guess this is from the UEFI loader

It looks like the partition table has also been wiped out. I can see the following when i run

```
gdisk -l /dev/sda

Partition table scan:
MBR : MBR only
BSD : Not present
APM : Not present
GPT : Not present

Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.

Partition table holds upto 128 entries. First usable sector is 34, last usable is ....
Number    Start    End      Size     Code   Name
1         2048     499711   243MiB   8300   Linux FIlesystem
2         501760   ...      931GiB   8E00   Linux LVM
```

Please help!

Comment: "My disk does not have a recognizable file system now" – how about partition(s)? I think the full output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` (or whatever your disk will be) would be relevant. Invoke with `sudo` if necessary. You need to boot some live CD Linux or maybe this Debian installer could provide console in advanced mode (although I don't know if `gdisk` will be there). Alternate, yet maybe a little less useful: `parted -l /dev/sda`. Please edit the question and paste the said output.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I've edited the question. Looks like the partitions are also wiped out

Comment: I have never seen `...` in `gdisk` output before. Did you alter the output while typing by hand? Anyway, [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) may find lost partitions by analyzing data, independently of current partition table.

Comment: yep. i was lazy in typing the huge figure :)

Comment: Do you have a backup image? Restore it.